# Is there any block that stops Players reaching the dispenser and lets arrows pass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Is there any block that Minecraft dispensers can shoot through, but makes the dispenser unreachable by players?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer oh so that's what he's trying to ask, I was briefly confused.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but you can place the dispenser facing upwards with blocks all around it and a pressure place on top of it and tell players to step on the pressure plate.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a list I came up with. I tried almost all blocks. Boldened blocks are better to use:

- Paintings (Although arrows will kill them)
- **Ladders** (placed on the dispenser)
- **Vines**
- **Banners**
- **Cobwebs**
- Double Tall Grass
- A Fence Door placed so that it opens when the dispenser is powered
- A (Iron or Wooden) Door placed so that it opens when the dispenser is powered
- An **Iron Trapdoor** (not Wood!)

And that's it. There is most probably no other block in Minecraft that can do that.

Comment: Aren't these all things, other than the upper slabs depending on placement, that would allow players to reach the dispenser?

Comment: @colorfusion Yes. "traversed" means accesed?

Comment: The original post said "can't reach the dispenser", before other people edited it.

Comment: @colorfusion Done; Is it OK now?

Comment: Yep, that seems to answer their question.

Comment: I seem to remember being able to shoot through iron bars. Not sure if those would work on a dispenser, though.

Comment: @TimPost Yes, it works when **a player** shoots, but not with a dispenser, because the bars will connect to the dispenser :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put lava there or use a glitch where dispencers can shoot though the ground.